# What terms I can use to say the something is very easy to do, to learn, etc?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, figures-of-speech

What terms I can use to say the something is very easy to do, to learn, etc?

I have thought about easy-peasy, like "this is easy-peasy to do", or "a piece of cake".

So, in general,

> Assembling this furniture is _________ [to do].

Is there a fun/cool way to say that? 
Some slang that is universally understood or something? 
Informal, light-hearted idioms are preferred. 
I don’t want technical bureaucratese
like “This should require only 20 minutes of your time”,
and things like “so easy that a caveman could do it”
seem unnecessarily pejorative.

Comment: I think easy-peasy and piece of cake ***are*** two fun ways to say that.  This only points out the fact that asked in this way means this is *primarily opinion-based*.

Comment: Also, "a snap," "a breeze," "easy as pie," "not rocket science," "not brain surgery," etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**A walk in the park**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-walk-in-the-park)

> something that is very easy to do, and usually pleasant

[**Easy as ABC**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/easy+as+ABC)

> Extremely easy, simple, or intuitive; requiring very little skill or effort.

[**Easy as falling off a log**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+as+easy+as+falling+off+a+log)

> To be extremely easy, simple, or intuitive; to require very little skill or effort. *After so many years as an accountant, doing taxes is as easy falling off a log for me. Boy, that test was easy as falling off of a log!*

[**Child's Play**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/child%27s+play)

> A very easy task. *Oh please, I've been playing guitar for 20 years—that song is child's play.*

Comment: I like "a walk in the park" and the word intuitive. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

The skill you have in mind has ***no learning curve*** to speak of.

Answer (score 1):

I propose **cinch** fron [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cinch) with the example usage

> the program was a **cinch** to use

Answer (score 1):

people say its "a no brainer", meaning so easy, doesn't require thinking/brains

Comment: Hi Tami, welcome to English Language & Usage. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference (e.g. dictionary definition) hyperlinked to the source. You can add this detail by using the [edit] link; for further guidance, see [answer]. I would be happy to upvote your answer once it has the extra detail :-)

Answer (score 1):

I’m astonished that nobody has mentioned ***as easy as pie********. 
It was one of the first things I thought of when I saw the question.

> [The Phrase Finder (www.phrases.org.uk)](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/as-easy-as-pie.html):
>
>   Very easy.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_easy_as_pie):
>
>   "
>   **As easy as pie**
>   " is a popular colloquial idiom
>     which is used to describe a task or experience as pleasurable and simple. 
>     The idiom does not refer to the making of a pie,
>     but rather to the act of consuming a pie ("as easy as eating a pie")
>     which is usually a simple and pleasurable experience. 
>     The phrase is often interchanged with
>   [piece of cake](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piece_of_cake)
>   ,
>     which shares the same connotation.
>
> [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/as-easy-as-pie):
>
>   **very easy**
>   :
>   *For Judy, getting a pilot’s license was easy as pie –
>     she seemed to have a natural talent for it.*
>
> [Idioms by The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/easy+as+pie):
>
>   Extremely easy, simple, or intuitive;
>     requiring very little skill or effort.
>   *After so many years as an accountant,
>     doing taxes is as easy as pie for me.*
>   *Boy, that test was easy as pie!*

[The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/as-easy-as-pie.html) goes on to say:

> #### What's the origin of the phrase 'As easy as pie'?
>
> There are many similes in English that have the form *'as X as Y'.* 
>   These almost always highlight some property - *X*,
>   and give an example of something that is well known to display that property
>   - *Y*; for example, 'as white as snow', 'as dead as a dodo'
>   and, risking a group slander action from our noble friends,
>   'as drunk as a lord'.
>
> How though are pies thought to be easy? 
>   They aren't especially easy to make; I know, I've tried it. 
>   The easiness comes with the eating - at least,
>   that was the view in 19th century America, where this phrase was coined. 
>   There are various mid 19th century US citations that,
>   whilst not using 'as easy as pie' verbatim,
>   do point to 'pie' being used to denote pleasantry and ease. 
>   'Pie' in this sense is archetypically American,
>   as American as apple pie in fact. 
>   The usage first comes in the phrase 'as nice as pie',
>   as found here in *Which: Right or Left?* in 1855:
>
> > "For nearly a week afterwards,
> >     the domestics observed significantly to each other,
> >     that Miss Isabella was as 'nice as pie!'"
>
> Mark Twain frequently used just 'pie' to mean pleasant or accommodating:
>   In *The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*, 1884,
>
> > "You're always as polite as pie to them."
> >     "So he took him to his own house, and dressed him up clean and nice,...
> >     and was just old pie to him, so to speak."
>
> Pie was also used at that time for something that was easy to accomplish;
>   for example, in The US magazine *Sporting Life*, May 1886:
>
> > "As for stealing second and third, it's like eating pie."
>
> ︙

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/easy+as+pie) offers these alternatives:

- **easy as falling** or **rolling off a log**
- **easy as ABC**

---

P.S. [Not One-Off Britishisms](https://notoneoffbritishisms.com/2012/01/16/easy-peasy/) suggests that “easy as pie”
is the American equivalent of “easy peasy”. 
I cannot find any indication that they are etymologically related. 
[Not One-Off Britishisms](https://notoneoffbritishisms.com/2012/01/16/easy-peasy/) goes on to say
“*easy peasy* is now officially all over the U.S.” 
I dispute this. 
As I mentioned, “easy as pie” popped into my (American) mind immediately,
whereas “easy peasy” makes me queasy (and my spell-checker rejects it). 
According to Google Ngrams, “easy peasy” is struggling
to become half as popular as “easy as pie” [in *British* English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=easy+as+pie%2Ceasy+peasy&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=18),

[image: Google Ngram — British English]

and is barely even registering [in American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=easy+as+pie%2Ceasy+peasy&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=17):

[image: Google Ngram — American English]

______________
***** OK, somebody posted “easy as pie” in a comment while I was writing this.

Answer (score 1):

***I could do it in my sleep*** suggests that
the task requires so little concentration and situational awareness
that it can be performed with a complete absence of those aids
(which are pretty much required to do anything).

> [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/can-do-something-in-your-sleep):
>     ***can do something in your sleep***
>
>     to be able to do something so easily that you do not need to think about it,
>       especially because you have done it so many times before
>     *I’ve driven there so many times, I could do it in my sleep.*
>
> [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/could-do-sth-in-your-sleep):
>     **could do *sth* in *your* sleep**
>
>     **If you could do something in your sleep,
>       you can do it very easily, usually because you have done it so often**
>     :
>     *I've made this recipe so many times I could do it in my sleep now.*
>
> [Idioms by The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/could+(do+something)+in+(one%27s)+sleep):
>     ***could (do something) in (one's) sleep***
>
>     Is able to do something with very little or no difficulty,
>       or complete or accomplish something
>       in a relaxed, carefree, or effortless manner.
>     *It took me a little while to get used to this job,
>       but now I could do it in my sleep!*
>     *You should ask Johnny for help—he could do this level of math in his sleep.*
>
> ***someone could do something in their sleep***
>
>     someone could do or accomplish something
>       with no effort or conscious thought.

Related: ***I could do it with my eyes closed***:

> [Idioms by The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/with+(one%27s)+eyes+closed):
>     ***with (one's) eyes closed***
>
>     With very little or no difficulty; in a relaxed, carefree,
>       or effortless manner.
>     *It took me a little while to get used to this job,
>       but now I could do it with my eyes closed!*
>     *You should ask Johnny for help—he does this level of math
>       with his eyes closed.*
>
> ***(be able to do something) with your eyes shut/closed***
>
>     (be able to do something) very easily,
>       especially because you have done it many times before:
>     *She’s driven up to Scotland so often that she can do it with her eyes shut.*
>
> ***with (one's) eyes closed***
>
>     Unaware of the risks involved.

It seems that these idioms generally refer to activities
that you can do easily because you have learned them thoroughly,
and not so much to the ease or difficulty of learning. 
And they are not quite as common as, for example, “easy as pie”.

Watch out for that last definition of ***with (one’s) eyes closed***;
i.e., it is the opposite of ***with (one’s) eyes (wide) open***.