# is there a word for the ability to be participated?

Tags: single-word-requests

The definition for **[accessibility](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/accessibility)**:

> the fact of being able to be reached or obtained easily

Accordingly, I want to ask is there a word like ***participatability** to express the ability to be able to be participated?

Comment: How about [**availability**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/availability)? *1.1 The state of being otherwise unoccupied; freedom to do something.* Although I am guessing as to what "to be participated" means. Can you please show an example sentence where the word is to be used?

Comment: _Reach, obtain_ and _access_ are transitive verbs. _Participate_ is not (or at least such usages are very rare). Do you mean _eligibility_ (the ability to take part in something)? Or 'open' as in 'the offer is open to all'?

Comment: It helps to be a bit more specific. For games and sports, [playability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gameplay#Playability) would work. [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/468872/what-terms-i-can-use-to-say-the-something-is-very-easy-to-do-to-learn-etc) is about things that are easy to do or learn. Participate is used of many things, some involving skill, others more about opportunity or openness to new people: hobbies, games, arts and crafts, politics, charitable works...

Comment: I think you’re looking for ***eligibility***.

Comment: to be participated is not grammatical.

Comment: Although "participability" is neither a word nor pleasant, I think it comes closer than "participatability" on both counts.

Answer (score 2):

**[Participatory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/participatory)** (MW):

> characterized by or involving participation
> *especially* : providing the opportunity for individual participation
>
> - participatory democracy
> - participatory management

Comment: Yes, ability to be participatory. Indeed. Why don't people upvote these??

Answer (score 0):

*Accessibility* is a characteristic of the object that is to be accessed by the person.

For example: *The accessibility of the building for those such as disabled folk who want access is good*.

You seem to ask for a parallel, something like:

XXXX is the characteristic of the object in which the subject is to participate

For example: *XXXX of the venture for all those such as minority groups who want to participate is good.*

After searching for XXXX, I suggest ***inclusivity*** as a property of the object that promotes the participation of the person.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inclusivity)
>
> inclusivity:
>
> the quality of trying to include many different types of people and treat them all fairly and equally

An example of how inclusivity relates to bringing people in and getting them to participate:

> [KellogInsight](https://insight.kellogg.northwestern.edu/article/how-to-make-inclusivity-more-than-just-an-office-buzzword)
> "... a company that aspires to be more inclusive should look at its numbers around recruitment, retention, engagement, and promotion"